# Best Layout Manager For Accomplishing This Task

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, springlayout

[image: Rough Idea Of What I'm Trying To Obtain]

I have (2) JTextAreas (input text & output text)

(2) JComboBoxes ( AutoDetect & TranslateTo)

Please see photo attached to see what the objective is.

I am trying to obtain this layout with a certain layout manager I have tried FlowLayout, SpringLayout and have not achieved desirable results with these. Here is my code

```
public class translate extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
/*
    Our Langauges of choice we can add more if desired in the future 
    */

    String[] nativeString = { "Auto-Detect"};
    String[] translateString = { "Español", "中文", "Francais", "Italiano", "Deutsche" , "English" };
     JComboBox nativeLanguage;
     JComboBox translateTo;
     JButton execute;
      final JPanel topRight;
      final JPanel topLeft;
      final JPanel bottomLeft;
      JPanel bottomRight;
      JLabel tR;
       JLabel tL;
      JLabel bR;
       JLabel bL;


      JRadioButton local;
      JRadioButton mainArea;
      JTextArea input;
      JTextArea output;

    public translate() throws Exception{

      super("Translation Service");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Translation Services Require A NetWork Function To Make Calls");
      Translate.setClientId("xxxxxxxxx");
      Translate.setClientSecret("Xxxxxxxxxxxx);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      setSize(700,400);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setResizable(true);
      setLookAndFeel();
      SpringLayout spring = new SpringLayout();
      setLayout(spring);


       input= new JTextArea();
      JScrollPane inScroll = new JScrollPane();
      input.add(inScroll);
     input.setEditable(true);
     input.setLineWrap(true);


     execute = new JButton("Translate");
    execute.addActionListener(this);
     output = new JTextArea();
     JScrollPane outScroll = new JScrollPane();
     output.add(outScroll);
      output.setEditable(true);
     output.setLineWrap(true);
     output.setVisible(true);
      /*
      Our JComboBoxes for user to selct langauge they want to choose
      */
      nativeLanguage = new JComboBox(nativeString);
      translateTo = new JComboBox(translateString);

      nativeLanguage.addActionListener(this);
      translateTo.addActionListener(this);
      // JLabels

      tR = new JLabel("Auto-Detect");
      tL = new JLabel ("Target Langauge");
      // FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
      SpringLayout sp = new SpringLayout();
      setLayout(sp);
      // setLayout(fl);
      //1
       topRight = new JPanel();
      // topRight.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topRight, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
       topRight.add(nativeLanguage);
       topRight.add(tR);


       //2
       topLeft = new JPanel();
      // topLeft.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topLeft, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
       topLeft.add(translateTo);
       topLeft.add(tL);

       //3

      bottomRight = new JPanel();
     // bottomRight.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomRight, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      bottomRight.add(input);

       //4
      bottomLeft = new JPanel();
    //  bottomLeft.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomLeft, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
     bottomLeft.add(output);




     add(topRight, SpringLayout.NORTH);
     add(topLeft, SpringLayout.NORTH);
     add(bottomRight, SpringLayout.SOUTH);
     add(bottomLeft, SpringLayout.SOUTH);

   setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: Use as many as you need to achieve the results you need, a layout is not generally a single level, but us made up n-depth containers, each focusing on the individual needs of a given area and built up to produce the over all effect you're aiming for

Comment: thanks MadProgrammer, yeah I believe i have included that this is the best layout(grid layout) have been plugging different layouts in and this seems to be more easy to work with and customize in this situation; attempting to resize everything at the moment or atleast my jtextareas as the look more like textfields

Comment: For my money, I'd be using compound `GridBagLayout`s, but that's me

Comment: Thanks for your input ill consider that as well in the design!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

70% complete everything is in its place per say: (imports left out)

```
public class translate extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
/*
    Our Langauges of choice we can add more if desired in the future 
    */
    DaWord mainArea = new DaWord();
    JMenuBar mainBar;
    JMenu menu;
    JMenuItem main,saveAs;

    String[] nativeString = { "Auto-Detect"};
    String[] translateString = { "Español", "中文", "Francais", "Italiano", "Deutsche" , "English" };
     JComboBox nativeLanguage;
     JComboBox translateTo;
     JButton execute;
      final JPanel topRight;
      final JPanel topLeft;
      final JPanel bottomLeft;
      JPanel bottomRight;
      JLabel tR;
       JLabel tL;
      JLabel bR;
       JLabel bL;
      JScrollPane scroll1;
      JScrollPane scroll2;

      JRadioButton local;
      JRadioButton mainAreas;
      JTextArea input;
      JTextArea output;

    public translate() throws Exception{

      super("Translation Service");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Translation Services Require A NetWork Function To Make Calls");
      Translate.setClientId("MYID");
      Translate.setClientSecret("shhItsASecret");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      setSize(900,450);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setResizable(true);
      setLookAndFeel();
      SpringLayout spring = new SpringLayout();
      setLayout(spring);
  javax.swing.border.Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
  setBackground(new Color(128, 218, 235));
      TitledBorder title1 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(blackline, "Input Text"); 
      mainBar = new JMenuBar();
      menu = new JMenu("Options");

      main = new JMenuItem("Export To Main");
      saveAs = new JMenuItem("Save As");
      menu.add(main);
      menu.add(saveAs);
      mainBar.add(menu);
     // add(mainBar);

     input= new JTextArea(35,35);
    scroll1 = new JScrollPane(input);
    //  scroll1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        //add("Center", scroll1);
     input.setEditable(true);
     input.setLineWrap(true);
  execute = new JButton("Translate");
    execute.addActionListener(this);

    TitledBorder title2 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(blackline, "Output Text");                   
     output = new JTextArea(35,35);
     scroll2 = new JScrollPane(output);
      // scroll2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
     scroll2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

     output.setEditable(true);
     output.setLineWrap(true);
     output.setVisible(true);
      /*
      Our JComboBoxes for user to selct langauge they want to choose
      */
      nativeLanguage = new JComboBox(nativeString);
      translateTo = new JComboBox(translateString);

      nativeLanguage.addActionListener(this);
      translateTo.addActionListener(this);
      // JLabels

      tR = new JLabel("Auto-Detect");
      tL = new JLabel ("Target Langauge");
      //  0,2 (2) rows across
     GridLayout flo = new GridLayout(0,2);
     setLayout(flo);
      // setLayout(fl);
      //1
       topRight = new JPanel();
      // topRight.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topRight, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
       topRight.add(nativeLanguage);
       topRight.add(tR);


       //2
       topLeft = new JPanel();
      // topLeft.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topLeft, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
       topLeft.add(translateTo);
       topLeft.add(tL);

       //3

      bottomRight = new JPanel();
     // bottomRight.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomRight, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      bottomRight.add(input);

       //4
      bottomLeft = new JPanel();
    //  bottomLeft.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomLeft, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
     bottomLeft.add(output);



     setJMenuBar(mainBar);
     add(topRight);
     add(topLeft);
     add(bottomRight);
     bottomRight.setBorder(title1);
     add(bottomLeft);
     bottomLeft.setBorder(title2);

   setVisible(true);


  saveAs.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
 public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        try {
            saveAsActionPerformed(evt);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DaWord.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void saveAsActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) throws Exception{
        Object trans = evt.getSource();
        if(trans==saveAs){
          save();
        }
    }
    private void save() throws FileNotFoundException {

       JFileChooser js2 = new JFileChooser();
       js2.setDialogTitle("Save As");
       js2.setCurrentDirectory(new File ("./"));
       int result = js2.showSaveDialog(null);
       if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
       String in1 = "This Is My Original Text:\n\n\n";
       String in2 = "This Is My Translated Text:\n\n\n";
       String content1 = input.getText();
       String content2 = output.getText();
       // all put in one
       String completa = in1+content1+in2+content2;
       File nef = js2.getSelectedFile();
       PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter(nef.getPath());
       fw.write(completa);
       fw.flush();

       }   
          }

});
  main.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        try {
            mainActionPerformed(evt);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DaWord.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void mainActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) throws Exception{
        Object mainS = evt.getSource();
        if(mainS==main){
          transfer();
        }
    }

          private void transfer() {
           String original = input.getText();
            String trans = output.getText();


            String intro1 = "This Is Your Original Text Below:\n\n\n";
            String intro2 = "This Is Your Translated Text Below:\n\n\n";


            mainArea.userField.append(intro1+original);
            mainArea.userField.append(intro2+trans);

          }

});





    }

  @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    /*
       JComboBox translateTo = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
    String box1 = (String) translateTo.getSelectedItem();

    */

   JComboBox nativeLanguage = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
   String newSelection = (String) translateTo.getSelectedItem();

   if (newSelection =="Español"){

        try { 
            eng2spanish();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(translate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}else if(newSelection=="Italiano"){
        try {
            eng2ital();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(translate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}else if(newSelection=="Francais"){
        try {
            eng2french();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(translate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}else if(newSelection=="中文"){
        try {
            eng2chin();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(translate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}else if(newSelection=="Duetche"){
        try {
            eng2ger();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(translate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


}else if(newSelection =="English"){
        try {
            eng2eng();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(translate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
   }



    }


private void setLookAndFeel() {
try{
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName");
}catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException |
UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e){
}
} 

      private void eng2spanish() throws Exception {

String userIn = input.getText();
 String spanishTranslation = Translate.execute(userIn, Language.SPANISH);
output.setText(spanishTranslation);
System.out.println(spanishTranslation);


    }

    private void eng2french() throws Exception { 

String userIn = input.getText();
 String frenchTranslation = Translate.execute(userIn, Language.FRENCH);
output.setText(frenchTranslation);

    }

    private void eng2chin() throws Exception {

String userIn = input.getText();
 String chinTranslation = Translate.execute(userIn, Language.CHINESE_TRADITIONAL);
output.setText(chinTranslation);

    }

    private void eng2ger() throws Exception {

String userIn = input.getText();
 String germanTranslation = Translate.execute(userIn, Language.GERMAN);
output.setText(germanTranslation);

    }



    private void eng2ital() throws Exception {

String userIn = input.getText();
 String italianTranslation = Translate.execute(userIn, Language.ITALIAN);
output.setText(italianTranslation);

    }
        private void eng2ind() throws Exception {

String userIn = input.getText();
 String hindiTranslation = Translate.execute(userIn, Language.HINDI);
output.setText(hindiTranslation);

    }

    private void eng2eng() throws Exception {

String userIn = input.getText();
 String engTranslation = Translate.execute(userIn, Language.ENGLISH);
output.setText(engTranslation); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone has any suggestions as always would love to hear them! keep in mind i know a few things in there are junk and will start house keeping soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the `GridLayout` works for you. If you want even more flexibility you can also use the `GridBagLayout`. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a link to all Layout Managers and linked examples.

But do you really want to do this with swing? It seems that you are at the beginning with the GUI-part of your project, so maybe you should think about using javafx instead of swing.

Comment: Thank you, I have decided to go with this had a hunch before i would end up using this guy but you kind of solidated my decision with your opinion, seems to get the desired effect 'quicker' than per say the other layout managers. Im going to post later for future question seekers the code I used when everything is organized :)